# $u_t=Au+F(u)$ where $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of $C_0$-semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

In Pavel's book: Nonlinear Evolution Operators and Semigroups - Applications to Partial Differential Equations, we have the following definitions and result:

Consider the following semilinear equation:

$$\tag{5.59}\begin{cases}u_t(t)=Au(t)+F(u(t)), ~0 \leq t \leq T,\\u(0)=u_0 \in H.  \end{cases} $$
where $A:D(A)\subset H \rightarrow H$ be the infinitesimal generator of $C_0$-semigroup $S(t)$ with $\|S(t)\|\leq 1$.

> **Definition 5.1.** (1)A function $u:[0,T]\rightarrow H$ is said to be a classical solution of $(5.59)$ if $u(0)=u_0$ and $$\tag{5.68}u \in C([0,T];D(A))\cap C^1([0,T];H)$$
>   and $(5.59)$ is satisfied. (2) The function $u$ is a classical solution on $[0,\infty[$ of $(5.59)$ if $(5.68)$ holds for every $T>0$ and $(5.59)$ is satisfied for every $t>0$.

By a mild solution of $(5.59)$ we mean a continuous function $u:[0,T] \rightarrow H$  satisfying $$\tag{5.69} u(t)=S(t)u_0+\int_{0}^{t} S(t-s)F(u(s))\, ds, ~0 \leq t \leq T.$$

> **Theorem 5.8** If $F:H\rightarrow H$ is locally Lipschitz then for every $u \in H$, there is a unique mild solution $u:[0,T_{\max}[\rightarrow H$ of $(5.59)$ with either $T_{\max}=+\infty$, or $T_{\max}<\infty$ and $\lim_{t \uparrow T_{\max}}\|u(t)\|=+\infty$. If $u_0 \in D(A)$, the mild solution $u$ is classical. (2) If $F$ is Lispschitz continuous, then $T_{max}=+\infty.$

My question:

> I would like to know if **Theorem 5.8** is valid for $ A $ being just the infinitesimal generator of a $C_0$-semigroup, that is, **without** the hypothesis that $\|S(t)\|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Theorem 5.8 has three parts: first part of (1), second part of (1), and (2). Following the books of [Goldstein](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wAONDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=goldstein+book+semigroups&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjz8Xd3cjoAhXOGbkGHcWkA5sQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=goldstein%20book%20semigroups&f=false) and [Pazy](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=DQvpBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=pazy+semigroups&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH5Nvs3cjoAhV-HbkGHcBwAXQQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=pazy%20semigroups&f=false) we can say that, if we drop the condition $\|S(t)\|\leq 1$, then:

- The first part of (1) remains valid (Thms 2.4 and 2.6 in p. 88-90 of Goldstein or Thm 1.4 in p. 185 of Pazy).
- The second part of (1) remains valid provided that (i) $F$ is continuously differentiable or (ii) $H$ is reflexive and $F$ is globally Lipschitz (Thms 1.5 and 1.6 in p. 187-189 of Pazy).
- (2) remains valid (Thm 2.5 in p. 89 of Goldstein).